# "Add a field" to CONTACTS

Tags: contacts

I want to add ADDRESS to one of my contacts.  I can "add a field" and it works fine.  Then I choose another contact, and I can't get that option.  Why is that?

Comment: What is your device name and mention its Android version?

Comment: It sounds like the 2 contacts come from different providers.

Answer (score 2):

Check, where your contact is stored. If it is stored on your SIM, then you can't add any field. To add a field, you must export this contact to your phone first.

Comment: how do I "export" the contact back to the phone, I cannot find that option.

Answer (score 0):

Check where these both contacts are coming from. Some services might support a set of features, some not. For example, in our feature phones, the contacts stored in SIM card could only save one phone number per contact, while the ones stored in phone could store multiple phone numbers along with other details as well.